# i am trying to center this image in the linear layout but its not working, what can i do

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to center the image in this linear layout, but it is only aligning to the left what can i do to fix this.

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
    
       <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `layout_gravity="center"` to the ImageView along with `orientation="vertical"` to the LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

A LinearLayout is intended to place multiple child Views in a line, vertically or horizontally. When you place a single child View, you don't have necessary to use a LinearLayout, but you can use just a FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: it didnt work could you test the code on your end

Comment: i see you used a frame layout which i just  tried and it worked but when i changed the layout to linear then image went back to the left, and i am also using two child views, one an image then other a textview. i used align text to center for the text and it moved to the middle howevee the image has since ceased to move to the movie

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="center"` to LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center">
    
       <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Or Add `android:layout_gravity="center"` to the ImageView

```
<ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
         />
```

It should work either way.

Comment: none of the above worked that was why i copied the code out maybe you test it from your end and help correct it